# Is there a simple way to convert json SV or C++ string to HV

Tags: c++, perl, swig, perl-xs, perlguts

I have a json string in my C++ class which I converted to SV and returning to my perl module as a scalar. I am parsing this scalar and convert it to json in my perl module.

Instead, I want to convert the json string to a HV or perl hash in my C++ class itself and return it as a perl hash to my perl module. Is there a simple way to do this.

I finally want to convert this json c string to JSON object;

Example:

In my test.cpp I have

```
std::string json = '{"A":123,"B":"ABC"}';
```

I am converting it to an SV (perl scalar) and sending it to my perl script.

In my test.pl, I am using JSON::XS to encode and decode it to either perl hash or json.

```
use JSON::XS;

my $perl_hash_or_arrayref  = decode_json $utf8_encoded_json_text;
my $utf8_encoded_json_text = encode_json $perl_hash_or_arrayref;
```

Actually what I am looking for is to convert the json encoded c++ string to native json and return it to my perl module. I am not sure if this is possible. One solution that i know is parse the json encoded string and convert it to a perl hash and send it to perl module and perl module converts it to native json. But in this case parsing a json encoded c++ string is costly because, my string can be a very long json structure.

but instead of this

1. Is there a simple way of returning a perl hash($perl_hash_or_arrayref) from my c++ file.
2. Or Return json($perl_hash_or_arrayref) from from c++ file.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sounds masochistic. If you haven't seen them already, you may be interested in the [`perlguts`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Working-with-HVs) or [`perlxs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html) manual sections.

Comment: Are you saying you want to write a JSON parser? Why not use an existing one?